# Printing of array elements php

Tags: php

I am new to php. please help me out.

consider the following data is present in an array $total

subtotal - 100
tax  - 10
paymentmethod - UPI
total - 110

when i use the following code (got the help from stack over flow)

```
<?php
            if ( $totals = $order->get_item_totals() ) {

                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {

                    echo $total['label']; 
                    echo $total['value']; 

                }
            }
        ?>
```

1Subtotal:200.00tax:10.00 via paymentmethod:UPI Total:110.00
is being displayed

how to display just

110
in a table (meaning i just need to echo $total[3]->value)

Comment: Please read up on how to use `if()` condtions

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya not sure what you mean.  Surely this will just set `$totals` to the return of the function and then process the `if()` if the return contains something.

Comment: @NigelRen OP just wants to print the value corresponding `total` label. One way is that he can use one more if condition inside the loop, to print only when label is `total`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to do this as a comment, but I can't right now, but:

First, in your if statement you're using a single `=` sign, but take a look here: [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

What's happening now is `$totals` is going to be set to `$order->get_item_totals()`, and I thing you don't want that.

Maybe you can use a while loop instead of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your $totals array has this structure:

```
$totals = [
    'subtotal' => '....',
    'tax' => '....',
    'paymentmethod' => '....',
    'total' => 110,
];
```

replace the foreach loop with:

echo $totals['total'];